# Filepond firebase revert

Tags: filepond

I'm trying to implement revert function but have an issue

```
revert(uniqueFileId, load, error) {
        const desertRef = this.storage.ref().child(uniqueFileId);
        desertRef.delete().then(function () {
          const index = self.files.indexOf(uniqueFileId);
          if (index > -1) {
            self.files.splice(index, 1);
          }
          load();
        }).catch(function (e) {
          switch (e.code) {
            case 'storage/canceled':
              break;
            default:
              error(e.message)
          }
        });
      },
```

full source
https://gist.github.com/boskiv/dd299cebcec4ca9ef8b8d792c7b4a420

In this case `uniqueFileId` in revert function contain full URL from storage.(https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koko-date-dev.appspot.com/o/gifts%2FhfvhV6Iou15pBj1mhA8b)

Is there option to get just filename in that case without complex parsing and string split

this in `revert` function
[image: this in revert function]

this in `process` function
[image: this in process function]

Answer (score 1):

The `uniqueFileId` is the string passed to the load callback inside the process function. So if you’re sure the name is unique you can pass the file name there and it should appear in the revert method.

See: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/

Comment: but, load method use url to load a preview ? right ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant load callback. Please read docs carefully.